# Assigning colors to classes using conditional statements using GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, visualisation

I am trying to assign colors to each of the class by checking the conditions (condition on - pixel values). But it doesn't check the `else` statements, it only checks the `if`:

```
if (image.gte(0.1).And(image.lt(0.2))):
  pal = ['orange']
elif (image.gte(0.2).And(image.lt(0.3))):
  pal= ['red']
elif (image.gte(0.3).And(image.lt(0.4))):
  pal = ['black']
elif (image.gte(0.4).And(image.lt(0.5))):
  pal = ['blue']
elif (image.gte(0.5).And(image.lt(0.6))):
  pal = ['green']
elif (image.gte(0.6).And(image.lt(0.7))):
  pal = ['yellow']
```

**Visualization:**

```
Map.addLayer(classes ,{'min': 0, 'max': 1, 'palette': pal}, 'Classes')
```

Why is this happening? And how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use client-side `if/else` conditional on server-side ee.Objects. When the first `if` is evaluated, it is coming back true because the ee.Object is represented as a string in the client (not per-pixel image value).

You can read more about server vs client [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server).

In your case, you could move the decimal place one position to the right and then round down, and then clamp to desired range, which gives you single digit integers in range [1,6]. Then specify 6 colors in your palette for visualization, setting `min` and `max` params to the clamped data range [1,6].

```js
var classes = image.multiply(10).floor().clamp(1, 6);
var pal = ['orange', 'red', 'black', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'];
Map.addLayer(classes, {min: 1, max: 6, palette: pal}, 'Classes');
```

Comment: It's giving me a map in yellow color only.

Comment: But I have found another solution.